# Play vimeo videos on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, iframe, vimeo, froogaloop

I have four vimeo iframes in a page. I want to play the video on mouseover and pause the video on mouseout. The following code works, but only for the last video. How can I modify it so that it will work for all the videos?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#wrapper .card {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player1" type="text/html" width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player2" type="text/html" width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player2"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player3" type="text/html" width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player3"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player4" type="text/html" width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player4"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.product-card-media').each(function() {
      var player = $("#" + this.id);
      froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);

      player.mouseover(function() {
          froogaloop.api('play');
      }).mouseout(function() {
          froogaloop.api('pause');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works perfectly for me

```
$('.product-card-vimeo-video').mouseover(function(){
var player = $("#" + this.id);
        froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);
        froogaloop.api('play');
        player.mouseout(function(){
            froogaloop.api('pause');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $.each that will loop through every id you should use     **$('#id).on('mouseover',function(){
});**

Please see the following working code

```js
$('.product-card-media').on('mouseover',function(){
  var player = $("#"+this.id);
      froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);

  player.mouseover(function(){
      froogaloop.api('play');
  }).mouseout(function(){
      froogaloop.api('pause');
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:85%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-top:50px;
}
#wrapper .card{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
       <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player1" type="text/html"  width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player1" ></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
       <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player2" type="text/html"  width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player2" ></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
       <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player3" type="text/html"  width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player3" ></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
       <iframe class="product-card-media" id="player4" type="text/html"  width="100%" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126309467?api=1&amp;player_id=player4" ></iframe>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $('.product-card-media').each(function(){
var player = $(".product-card-media");
    froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);

player.mouseover(function(){
    froogaloop.api('play');
}).mouseout(function(){
    froogaloop.api('pause');
});
});
```

Check the PEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMLmVQ

Comment: This one is not functional properly. When you hover over second or else video than first, it will start the first one.